# How to launch another blank terminal in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

When I launch another terminal in Kali Linux with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, I can see Shell No. 2 tab created.

However, it is just a copy of Shell No. 1 and all the commands I ran on Shell No. 1 are visible on Shell No. 2.

I want to launch another terminal as blank, and run separate commands there.

Please tell me how to set up?

Comment: It is what it is.  Posted from Kali.  Ubuntu is almost the same.

Comment: Remember that Kali is not a normal OS and only people able to deal with Kali on its terms can make peace with it.